# Hiding Overflow-x of a fixed position DIV on outer DIVs

Tags: css, html, css-position, fixed

I have a layout like this:

```
<div class="mainContent" style="overflow-y: scroll !important; width: 100%">
  <div class="leftPanel" style="overflow: hidden; width: 225px;">
  </div>
  <div class="rightPanel" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="dataPanel" style="width:21355px; height:3253px;">
      <div class="topPanel"  style="position:fixed; width:21355px;">
      </div>
      <div class="bottomPanel">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The topPanel needs to be in a fixed position so that it doesn't scroll vertically (y-axis) with the rest of the data contained within mainContent but topPanel also needs to stay within the confines of rightPanel along the x-axis.  I tried using overflow-x: hidden on every outer div but due to having position:fixed on topPanel, it ignores that attribute.

I have been searching for awhile and the closest solution I had found was to use:

```
clip: rect(0px 750px 900px 0px);
```

which would cut off  topPanel's overflow along the x-axis, but if a user scrolled to the left or right (which they will do) it would need to be readjusted each time which doesn't seem like a plausible solution.

See the fiddle here.  Notice the "Top" that overflows to the right outside of all div containers.

http://jsfiddle.net/3RLYm/

Comment: Share your CSS as well.

Comment: The only CSS attributes applied are those in the "style" attribute of the DIVs above.  The class is nothing more than an identifier in this case.

Comment: Using something like [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with an example of your problem helps a ton to visualize it and saves those looking extra time to go troubleshoot for ya. Just a tip.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Chris W.  I added the fiddle.  The "Top" overflowing to the right identifies the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are using position:fixed; when you use fixed positioning you are taking the element out of the regular flow of the document and bolting it to a specific area. Once this is done the overflow attributes no longer apply. In the example below I used the 'right' and 'left' properties to lock the sides of the "top" div and removed the 'width'. Obviously you will have to adjust those values to suite your needs but that is the direction I would go.

```
topPanel
{
position: fixed;
right: 10px;
left: 250px;
border: solid 4px purple;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3RLYm/35/

Comment: Right and that is the problem I'm having.  Adjusting right and left just shifts the overflow as I've tried this as well.

I appreciate your insight but what I'm looking for is a workaround for the issue caused by fixed positioning.

Comment: If you remove the 'width' property and use the right and left positioning to determine how wide the top header is there will be no overflow. See my fiddle link up top to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: I understand that but I need the width in there to match up with the "dataPanel" width.  They need to be the same width to run flush with each other.